# Servidor Express se queda colgado con Sockets

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, socket

Tengo un problema, estoy montando un servidor express con Sockets (modulo socketcluster-server) pero cuando estoy atacando con peticiones http se me queda bloqueado el express al cabo de 20 peticiones aproximadamente, provocando que los Sockets (cliente) avisen de que se han quedado sin conexion.

¿Ha alguien le ha ocurrido? ¿alguna idea que me pueda ayudar resolver este problema?

Adjunto el código de express y como gestiono el Socket en el back:

express.js

```
const http = require('http'),
 express = require('express'),
    socket = require('./socket'),
    HOST = 'localhost',
    PORT = 8000,
 bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express()

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>res.send({status:"ok"}))

socket.init(httpServer,HOST,PORT)

httpServer.listen(PORT,HOST);

httpServer.on('listening', () =>{
    console.log('Express server started on port %s at %s', httpServer.address().port, httpServer.address().address);
});
```

socket.js

```
const socketClusterServer = require('socketcluster-server')

module.exports = (() => {

    let scServer

    const createInstance = (httpServer, host, port) => {
        if (!scServer)
            scServer = socketClusterServer.attach(httpServer, {host, port});

        scServer.on('connection', function (socket) {
            console.log('socker: ', scServer.clientsCount)

            socket.on('client',getMessageByClient)

        })
    }

    const getMessageByClient = (data) => {
        if (data.channel)
            sendMessage(data.channel, data)
        scServer.removeListener('client', getMessageByClient)
    }

    const sendMessage = (channel, message) => scServer.exchange.publish(channel, JSON.stringify(message))

    const close = () => scServer.close()

    return {
        init: (httpServer, host, port) => createInstance(httpServer, host, port),
        sendMessage: (channel, message) => sendMessage(channel, message),
        close: () => close()
    }
})()
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final después de probar muchas formas, he podido solucionar este problema de la siguiente manera:

```
// Variables de entorno
const { env: { HOST, PORT }} = process

//Creamos un servidor http
const httpServer = require('http')

//Inicializamos express
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// Aquí vendría las configuraciones y rutas de express

// Adjuntamos express a nuestro servidor http
httpServer.on('request', app)

// Hacemos que el socket se inicialice con el al servidor Http
const socket = require('./socket')
socket.init(httpServer, HOST)

// Inicializamos el Servidor
httpServer.listen(PORT, HOST)

httpServer.on('listening', async () => {

   console.info(`Server started on port ${httpServer.address().port} at ${httpServer.address().address}`)
})
```

Actualmente esta funcionando correctamente, recibe peticiones express y sockets sin ningún bloqueo.

Espero que esto le pueda ayudar a alguien.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

a ver si esto puede ayudarte, este ejemplo es con `SocketIO` pero pienso que puede servir.

`SocketIO` necesita un servidor para arrancar, tú ya tienes uno cuando haces `const app = express()`, no necesitas crear otro con `const httpServer = http.createServer(app);`. Intenta guardar el de **express** en una **const** y esa se la pasa al **socket**.

```
const express = require('express');
const SocketIO = require('socket.io');
const app = express()
...
...
const server = app.listen(console.log('listening on port 3000'));

const io = SocketIO(server);

io.on('connection', () => {
  console.log('client connect');
});
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola @codemcu, ante todo gracias por responde.
Lo he probado pero sigue bloqueando el servidor express, cuando uso solo peticiones Http funciona correctamente pero cuando combino peticiones Http con peticiones de los Sockets acaba bloqueando el servidor, y eso que solo testeo con un Socket.

Comment: Tenía la esperanza de que el bug venía por tener dos servers